# is there a way to make a jar with the Eclipse generated ant script?

Tags: ant, jar, eclipse-neon

To my surprise the `build.xml` file generated by Eclipse (Neon) for Java has no element containing an invocation of a `jar` task. As often is the case with code generation I think you have to use it and make no edits so that you can regenerate - or - avoid code generation completely. A comment in the generated file suggests it might be possible to avoid edits by extending the capabilities by importing.

```
<!-- WARNING: Eclipse auto-generated file.
              Any modifications will be overwritten.
              To include a user specific buildfile here, simply create one in the same
              directory with the processing instruction <?eclipse.ant.import?>
              as the first entry and export the buildfile again. -->
```

I thought I would be able to use the `<?eclipse.ant.import?>` element in an second file called `export.xml`. In `ant` scripting there is supposed to be one project per buildfile so now there is a second project with a dependency on a target in the first project.

Regenerating `build.xml` reveals that it contains an "import" as expected.

`<import file="export.xml"/>`

Unfortunately this does not work. Running `ant`, which I do from the command line, just seems to result in the export/`jar` project being ignored.

The generated script with the import element (nested on the 7th line)...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project basedir="." default="build" name="ohana1">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
    <property name="target" value="1.8"/>
    <property name="source" value="1.8"/>
    <import file="export.xml"/>
    <path id="ohana1.classpath">
        <pathelement location="bin"/>
        <pathelement location="../export/ohana1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar"/>
    </path>
    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="bin"/>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
            <fileset dir="src">
                <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="bin"/>
    </target>
    <target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
    <target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
    <target name="build-subprojects"/>
    <target depends="init" name="build-project">
        <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
        <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">
            <src path="src"/>
            <classpath refid="ohana1.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
    <target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects"/>
    <target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
        <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </copy>
        <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
            <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </unzip>
    </target>
    <target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
        <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
        <antcall target="build"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

The `export.xml` file meant to make a `jar`...

```
<?eclipse.ant.import?>
<project basedir="." default="export" name="ohana1Export">
    <target depends="build,make-jar" name="export"/>
    <target name="make-jar">
        <jar destfile="../export/ohana1/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="bin"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Note that the Eclipse Ant editor complains about this `export.xml` file because the target named `build`, which is a dependency, does not exist in this project/buildfile. The `build` target is in the generated `build.xml`. That error might be coming from a "dumb" editor so I went ahead to do a run of `ant`. Invoking `ant` from the command line I find that there is no `jar` file made.

Should I conclude that Eclipse's `ant` script generator is useless if you need to export a `.jar` file and that a human should maintain the `ant` script that meets all the requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in my opinion the exported `build.xml` is useless, as of Eclipse Neon, if the intention is to make a `.jar`.

Specifically do the following.

- Manually write the trivial `ant` script that exports a `.jar`. The link at the bottom of this post has verbatim text on what the script might look like. You can use the built-in `Xml Editor` via `New > Other > XML > XML File` to create this new file which might be called `makeJar.xml` and save it. If the icon shown in the `Package Explorer` is still a plain XML file icon refreshing the project may change the icon to an `Ant` file icon. In the future, you can use `Open With` to get the `Ant Editor` instead of the `XML Editor`. This script will replace the manual exporting of a `.jar` that the user would otherwise perform via Eclipse.
- This script can be added to `Project > Properties > Builders`. It would be placed second in the list of Builders. First in the list of Builders is the `Java Builder` which should already exist. When an Eclipse build is invoked the entire list of Builders will be processed in the order shown in the list of Builders. Thus not only will `.class` files be generated but also the `.jar`.

What is achieved is greater automation since the `.class` generation and `.jar` generation are now integrated, which arguably was the point of using the exported `build.xml` in a failed attempt to generate the `.jar`.

Here is the dialog at `Project > Properties > Builders` that you can use to create a new Builder. Select `New` then select `Ant Builder`. I gave the name `makeJar` to the new `Builder`.

[image: Builders]

Here is the dialog for the new `Ant` Builder that will allow you to browse to your `buildfile` which is your manually written `Ant` script that creates a `.jar` file. In this example the script is `makeJar.xml`. It also allows you to browse to the `base directory` to be used when the script is run.

[image: Configuration of the new Ant Builder]

After setting up the new Builder, a project "clean" or project "build" will create `.class` files and also the `.jar`.

---

Eclipse's documentation on this subject is at the link. Note that it seems impossible to link the exact page that contains the instructions so you have to browse down the documentation tree to the section about "Ant buildfiles as project builders".

[Link to Eclipse and Ant](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-81_basics.htm)